# R list within matrix to dataframe conversion

Tags: r, list, dataframe

R struggles. I am using the following to extract quotations from text, with multiple results on a large datset. I am trying to have the output be a character string within a dataframe, so I can easily share this as an csv with others.

Sample data:

```
normalCase <- 'He said, "I am a test," very quickly.'
endCase <- 'This is a long quote, which we said, "Would never happen."'
shortCase <- 'A "quote" yo';
beginningCase <- '"I said this," he said quickly';
multipleCase <- 'When asked, "No," said Sam "I do not like green eggs and ham."'
testdata = c(normalCase,endCase,shortCase,beginningCase,multipleCase)
```

Using the following to extract quotations and a buffer of characters:

```
result <-function(testdata) {
  str_extract_all(testdata, '[^\"]?{15}"[^\"]+"[^\"]?{15}')
}
extract <- sapply(testdata, FUN=result)
```

The extract is a list within a matrix. However, I want the extract to be a character string that I can later merge to a dataframe as a column. How do I convert this?

Comment: Not sure about the expected output.  May be you need to use `yourdat$Col <- unlist(extract, use.names=FALSE)`

Comment: how do yo uwant the character string to look? do you want all of the text in one string?

Comment: all text in one string, where the extract is equal to that of the row. So ideally there would be a string length of 5 for the 5 case studies in the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Code

```
normalCase <- 'He said, "I am a test," very quickly.'
endCase <- 'This is a long quote, which we said, "Would never happen."'
shortCase <- 'A "quote" yo';
beginningCase <- '"I said this," he said quickly';
multipleCase <- 'When asked, "No," said Sam "I do not like green eggs and ham."'
testdata = c(normalCase,endCase,shortCase,beginningCase,multipleCase)

# extract quotations
gsub(pattern = "[^\"]*((?:\"[^\"]*\")|$)", replacement = "\\1 ", x = testdata)
```

#### Output

```
[1] "\"I am a test,\"  "                            
[2] "\"Would never happen.\" "                      
[3] "\"quote\"  "                                   
[4] "\"I said this,\"  "                            
[5] "\"No,\" \"I do not like green eggs and ham.\" "
```

#### Explanation

- `pattern = "[^\"]"` will match with any character except a double quote
- `pattern = "[^\"]*"` will match with any character except a double quote 0 or more times
- `pattern = "\"[^\"]*\""` will match with a double quote, then any
  character except a double quote 0 or more times, then another double
  quote (i.e.) quotations
- `pattern = "(?:\"[^\"]*\")"` will match with quotations, but wont capture
  it
- `pattern = "((?:\"[^\"]*\")|$)"` will match with quotations or endOfString,
  and capture it. Note that this is the first group we capture
- `replacement = "\\1 "` will replace with the first group we captured followed by a space